# Why does java.lang.Math extend java.lang.Object?

Tags: java, inheritance

According to the Java API for the [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class, Math extends the Object class:

```
public final class Math extends Object
```

However, Math does not inherit Object's methods, and you also cannot construct a Math object (EDIT: this statement is false and partly false; see below).

My question is then why is this done? If it is an object, then it should have the bare-bones methods from Object. If it is not an object, then I feel like it should not be extending Object.

And, assuming there is a good reason for extending Object, how is it done? In other words, how are the inherited methods and constructor suppressed?

Math is the foremost example in my mind of this kind of static definition class (I guess you'd call it that?), but this question may also apply to classes that have a similar purpose.

EDIT: So I'm aware that all classes implicitly extend Object. What's bothering me is that to me there's a logical disconnect between the notion of an "object" in theory-- something with a state and associated functionality-- and what's being done here.

Comment: From the Oracle Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html): "In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of `Object`."

Comment: You have to revisit the Java tutorial again mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math` *does* inherit `Object`'s methods.  Every class in Java ultimately *has to* inherit from `Object`.  But since you can't construct `Math` objects, it doesn't matter.  The methods are inherited, but without being able to construct an instance you can't ever use them from `Math`.

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you know what the mechanism is to disable the inherited constructor?

Comment: Constructors are not inherited, they are chained.  The simplest way to disable creation of objects of a class is to define one constructor and make it private: `private Math() { }`

Comment: You *can* construct `Math` objects, the default constructor is just not *visible* by default.  This can be overridden at runtime using reflection.  Not that it's useful or recommended to do so, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: @aroth In this case, perhaps.  But IIRC, the recommended way to make "static" classes is to declare them `abstract final`, which would prevent instances from being created, even via reflection.  (In fact, in C#, declaring a `static` class actually emits a `sealed abstract` class, where `sealed` means the same thing as Java's `final`.)

Comment: Okay, so this makes more sense. I amended the end of my question. It just seems like this is kind of a hackish way of providing basic library functionality by making these definitions classes like Math masquerade as an Object.

Comment: @entay All classes have to inherit from `Object`.  What mechanism do you propose then, given this constraint?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. So it may be a mismatch of what the theory is and what needs to happen in practice, and this is just the best way around it.

Comment: By the way, sorry that this appears to be an outlandishly stupid question (based on the downvotes). I'm a student, just trying to reconcile what I thought an object has to be with how things are implemented.

Comment: What you're asking is basically for a way to put functions in a namespace.  The language designers probably could have added a "module" or some such construct to accomplish this, but putting static methods on a class that can't be constructed has exactly the same effects, no performance overhead, and doesn't require any additional language construct.

Comment: @entay You're skipping one of the most important aspects of OOP that is the intention of a class. Math is not supposed to be instantiated, just referred with static calls to methods that do not depend from a context. Since you can't instantiate it through "normal" means there's no real reason to do it.

Comment: You all have explained it very clearly, I understand now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Object is the super class of everything. All classes extend Object

Comment: Nitpick - it is the superclass of every reference type; i.e. all explicitly declared classes and all array types.  However, it is not the superclass of **everything**.  For instance it is not the superclass of `int`.  The primitive types don't have superclasses.

Answer (score 3):

Every class implicitly extends `Object` unless they extend another class (Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance).

Still! by extending another class you're, in the very end, extending `Object`, because the last class that doesn't extend another particular class extends `Object`.

The concept behind this "default inheritance" can be extracted directly from `Object`'s JavaDoc:

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has
>   Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the
>   methods of this class.

*EDIT:* Math does inherit `Object`'s methods. It does not override them tough and the calls are derived to the implementations of the superclass.

You should pay attention to an important aspect of the `Math` class. The constants and methods it defines are mainly static. Mathematical functions do not depend of a particular instance of the class because those calculations are independent of the context.

You have no particular reason to create an instance of the Math class and that's why its constructor is not visible. You cannot do `Math m = new Math()` and that's why you don't see methods such as `equals` or `hashcode`. In particular since the class is final and can't be extended, you cannot create a sublclass that defines them. IMHO it would be pointless.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is the super class of every java class. An you are mistaken that `Math` does inherit object's methods.

If you want more see the source.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Math.java.html

Comment: Thank you, the source was helpful.